# Statistical approach for football competition

Tags: combinatorics, operations-research

There are 10 teams in a club.
Each week, there are 3 games where each team plays another team from the same club.
All games are played in the same park. The park has 5 pitches. There are 5 teams that stay on their pitch for the 3 games, and the other 5 teams rotate in a clockwise direction for each game. There are about 20 weeks in the season. What is the best approach to assign games so that each team plays another team a roughly equal amount of times?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: I can see by the way I have written the question that it looks like something from a textbook. But it is honestly not, I am looking for some guidance on where to start looking for a better way to allocate games - currently it is just a spreadsheet. Thanks

Comment: Could you give some more context, or is the information complete? Are you an organizer for these games, maybe?

Comment: Are you organizing these events, maybe? The sister site https://or.stackexchange.com/  could be a better match for this question ... if you want we can move it there for you. But why tha `bayesian` tag? I cant see anything BAyesian there ...

Comment: Yes - organising the draw, perhaps OR is better. Bayesian was a guess . The complicating factor for me is the fact that we have half the teams moving , but they can’t move anywhere they like, they all just move one pitch in the same direction.

Comment: I reopened. Maybe you can add some more information?

Comment: Thanks. I have found some round robin information which I think will help me. Thanks for your help

Comment: Turns out was a Round robin problem